# Simpler way of achieving some sort of key:key:list in Redis?

Tags: java, redis, jedis

So, I have a list of ranks, each rank has a list of permissions. I need to store them in Redis.

The problem being is that the server downloading these ranks from Redis doesn't know how many ranks there are / the names of the ranks.

So I decided to put "ranks":list of ranks into redis, and then "rank":list of permissions, that way the server can iterate through the "ranks" list, and grab the list off permissions through the "rank" part.

However, this is a bit inefficient as I have to create two pipelines to do this.

I was wondering if there was a way to create like a key:key:list data type on Redis?

For example,

"ranks", rank0, list of permissions

"ranks", rank1, list of permissions

etc.

Currently I have

"ranks", list of ranks

"rank0", list of permissions

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Why you just use key as "ranks:rank0" -> list of permissions, "ranks:rank1" -> list of permissions?

Comment: @alpert because the server that is getting the rank data from Redis does not know the name of the ranks, so it wouldn't know what "rank0" is. That's why I use a key called "ranks" which returns a list of the ranks, so that the server can use that info to retrieve the individual rank data.

Comment: @Archie you can try `Redis-Hash` because nested data types are not allowed in Redis. The hash key would be `ranks` you can have fields as rank0:permission1 rank0:permission2 so on.

Comment: @Gunasekar each rank has a List<String> of permissions, that's a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two options:

- Create a Lua script for the task. The advantage is you'll remove all the back-and-forth network round-trips you need (but you still need to execute all the LRANGE calls to all the lists)
- Save keys in a hash, and the value of the hash is a serialized version of the list (JSON, for example). In your code, you'd make one call to Redis, but you'll need to process that information somehow

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. Probably going to stick with my original idea since I only use the code once when the application starts! Your replies are really helpful as may have to use his again in the future.